# Parse JSON Response Array using ForEach component in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a requirement to parse JSON response which contain array of products(P1,P2,P3,etc.). Each product contains multiple information like name, type, cost, etc.

I need to read each product one by one and append additional data got from the another service into an new JSON output. I am thinking of using ForEach component of WSO2 ESB to iterate each product one by one.

Problem is that ForEach component uses ForEachExpression which expects XML expression in the configuration.

Please suggest on the method to parse array of JSON response one by one in WSO2 ESB.

/Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Can use both Iterate or ForEach mediator for iterating the JSON array, since both are content aware mediators and support JSON.

Which one to use depends upon the specific usecase as Iterate provides the capability to use call / callout / send mediators in the sequence whereas ForEach doesn´t allow it.

For the below given sample JSON request, the following iteration works and the JSON array and objects can be referred like the same.

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "product":{
            "id":"1234",
            "size":"20",
            "quantity":"1",
            "price":"990",
            "type":"Electronics",
            "store":{
               "id":"001"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}

<iterate expression="//products" id="PRD_ITR">
    <target>
      <sequence>
        <sequence key="Product_Enrich_Sequence_s"/>
        <!-- For example, Switching sequence based on the product type -->
        <switch source="//products/product/type">
          <case regex="Computer">
            <sequence key="Computer_Product_Enrich_Sequence_s"/>
          </case>
          <case regex="Mobile">
            <sequence key="Mobile_Product_Enrich_Sequence_s"/>
          </case>
          <case regex="Grocery">
            <sequence key="GR_Product_Enrich_Sequence_s"/>
          </case>
          <default>
            <!-- default stuff --!>
          </default>
        </switch>
      </sequence>
    </target>
  </iterate>
```

FYR

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Iterate+Mediator

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/ForEach+Mediator

Note: tested in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

Comment: I need to fetch the value of each product one by one and then put it back into single JSON response. Does WSO2 ESB internally converts all kind of message type like JSON, etc. into XML for further processing?

Comment: yes.. its works like that. Converts the json into xml for its internal processing. You can specify the final response to be JSON or process it by XSLT or payloadfactory. Did the above answer work?

Comment: don't you think it can seriously hurt performance for internally converting from JSON to XML for JSON file of more than 8000 lines? At the same time, I have noticed that internal conversion from JSON to XML is giving wrong results in the sense, correct XML structure is not getting generated. Do we have any restrictions here?

Comment: yes, there is a overhead in this internal conversion. When you talk about wrong results during conversion, it depends upon the JSON formatters and builders that you are using. WSO2 gives few options with this. Check your's and its respective documentation. Might also need some XSLT mediation for few cases..